# How to get an outcome value of h:link from javascript function in JSF?

Tags: jsf, xhtml

I have an `h:link` element like this

```
<h:link outcome="/overview.xhtml?source=menu"
        title="Overview">
            <div>...</div>
</h:link>
```

And I'd like to add a boolean variable `phone` to the URI address based on the `MobileMatcher` from JavaScript.

In other words, I'd like to set the outcome like this:

```
<h:link outcome="getOverviewURI()"
        title="Overview">
            <div>...</div>
</h:link>
```

where `getOverviewURI()` is the function returning the string URI:

```
function getOverviewURI() {
    let URI = '/overview.xhtml?phone=';
    URI += MobileMatcher.isMobile() ? "true" : "false";
    return URI;
}
```

However the `h:link` expects an actual string and ignores JavaScript function call. I tried using semicolon at the end of the function call which made the link display a warning that it wasn't able to parse the address. I also tried using plain JS in there and `"javascript:getOverviewURI()"` which supposedly works with `<a href="...">` tag and I also tried to directly change the attribute of the DOM element, but it is deeply nested and I seem to be unable to rewrite it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get a outcome in h:link from a javascript function,  because JSF always render server side and will try to resolve server side what to put on propertie href of the rendered tag "a". If you need a dynamic outcome, then then function "getOverviewURI()" should become a method on  a backing bean if possible.

Or if you only want to navigate,  you could use the "onclick" event with the following changes:

```
<h:link onclick="getOverviewURI()"
        title="Overview">
            <div>...</div>
</h:link>

function getOverviewURI() {
    let URI = window.location.hostname +'/overview.xhtml?phone=';
    URI += MobileMatcher.isMobile() ? "true" : "false";
    window.location.href =URI;
}
```

Beware there are drawbacks in using js to navigate jsf applications, like not updating back beans.

Comment: That's unfortunate since I don't think there's a way for the backing bean to know whether the user is on a phone or on desktop, is there?

Comment: You can try always try to parse the user agent on the backing bean. Or another solution would be use remote command from prime faces http://www.primefaces.org:8080/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml?jfwid=fd729 (third example receive values back), to execute detection logic in js and send results to a session scoped bean.